# ASP.NET Core RC2 Project -What's a Services folder for?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

When you create an ASP.NET Core RC2 project using VS2015, you get a built-in `Services folder`. Can someone please provide explanation with examples of Service folder usage. Or some links that may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.NET loads some default **prepackaged services** into the container and makes them available for the application. If you want to add your own service : 
1. You create service inside Services folder
2. Register created service on **ConfigureServices**(after that, asp.net container will know about that service and can inject instance of that service into methods like Configure and into Views, Controllers…)
3. Finally, add that service inside the **Configure method** ( in order to prepackage it like default services)

Answer (score 9):

Maybe, you've read the documentation about this release candidate version. https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html

> ASP.NET Core is designed from the ground up to support and leverage dependency injection. ASP.NET Core applications can leverage built-in framework services by having them injected into methods in the Startup class, and application services can be configured for injection as well. The default services container provided by ASP.NET Core provides a minimal feature set and is not intended to replace other containers.

**A service**, in this context , refers to a class instance which provides some operations or data to other parts of your application. Don't misunderstand it, a service doesn't refer to a web service but it could be.

Asp.net core has a integrated IoC container, and you can set up dependencies in your startup class.

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddMvc();

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
}
```

Comment: Then how do one creates a custom service, for example, to `retrieve data from a SQL database` and display it in a, say, dropdown in ASP.NET Core?